# Equality of spans

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space ***V***, whose dimension and base are unknown. And I also have sets ***S1*** and ***S2*** which are subsets of ***V***. Also, ***S1*** is the subset of ***S2*** and ***S2*** is the subset of ***span(S1)***. Now, I need to prove that if this is true, then ***span(S1) = span(S2)***.

I was wondering if anyone could help with this one, since I am really clueless about it.

I understand that the ***span(S1)*** is the smallest subspace in ***V*** that contains ***S1***. Same goes for ***S2***.

So, ***S1*** is a subset of ***span(S1)*** and ***S2*** is a subset of ***span(S2)***. And since ***S1*** is the subset of ***S2***, ***S1*** is also a subset of ***span(S2)***.

This is what I have managed to figure out, if I am correct. But I don't know how to continue from here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\vee S$ for the span of a set $S$. If $S_1 \subset S_2$ then it is always true that $\vee S_1 \subset \vee S_2$. Furthermore, since $S_2 \subset \vee S_1$ the definition of the span allows each member of $S_2$ to be written as a linear combination of members of $S_1$. Since $\vee S_2$ consists of all linear combinations of members of $S_2$, which in turn can be written as linear combinations of members of $S_1$, it must be that $\vee S_2 \subset \vee S_1$, from which the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

$S_1 \subset S_2$, thus span$(S_1)\subset$ span$(S_2)$

$S_2 \subset$ span$(S_1)$ and span$(S_1)$ is closed for linear combinations. Thus span$(S_2)$ $\subset$ span$(S_1)$

Thus those two spans are equal.